# K-Ary Tree and Symmetric Search/Visit in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I'm dealing with a big problem: I've almost finished my first universary project, but now I'm stuck.

I need to create a method (in java language) to symmetrically visit ak-ary tree (These are the words of my professor: a symmetrical visit of a k-ary tree is the symmetrical visit subtrees from the first to (k/2)-th, followed by the visit of the root, followed by the symmetrical visit of subtrees from (k/2)-th to k-th ("to visit a node" means access to information contained therein, "to visit a subtree" means the visit of all nodes in the subtree).

I created two classes to implement k-ary trees: Node and Tree.

**Node.java:**

```
Field Summary:

List<Node<T>> children; //the children of the current node
T info; //property that the node contain
static int maxNrOfChildren; //equals to k-arity of the tree
Node<T> parent; //the parent of current node

Constructor Summary:
Node(T info) //creates a node containing some informations

Method Summary
void addChild(Node<T> childNode) //add a child to a node
void addChildAtIndex(Node<T> childNode, int index) //add a child to a node at a specific index
List<Node<T>> getChildren() //returns a list of the children of a node
T getInfo() //returns the informations contained in a node
void setInfo(T info) //set an information to a node
java.util.List<T> getInfoChildrenOfNode() //returns a list containing all the infos conitaned in the children of a node
int getNumberOfChildren() //return the number of children of a node
Node<T> getParent() //returns the parent of a node
boolean isLeaf() //returns true if a node is a leaf
```

**Tree.java:**

```
Field Summary:

int ar; //equals to k-arity of the tree (int k of the constructor)
Node<T> root; //the root node of a tree

Constructor Summary:
Tree(int k) //creates a Tree of k arity

Method Summary:
void addRoot(T info) //add a root to a tree
void changeRoot(T info) //changes the root of a tree creating a new one with new info
Node<T> getRoot() //return the root of the current tree
void addNewNodeVasithChildOfNodeU(Node<T> u, T info, int i) //add a new node as it is the i-th child of the node u
int getHeight() //returns the height of the tree
int getHeight(Node<T> n) //returns the height from a specific node
void innesta(Node<T> u, Tree<T> subTree) //add a tree (subtree) as a child of a node of the principal tree
int numberOfNodesInTree() //returns the number of the nodes in the tree
int numberOfNodesInTree(Node<T> node) //returns the number of the nodes in the tree starting from a specific node
LinkedList<T> visitaBFS() //returns a list of the infos obtained with a BFS
LinkedList<T> visitaDFSA() //returns a list of the infos obtained with a DFS (pre-order)
LinkedList<T> visitaDFSP() //returns a list of the infos obtained with a DFS (post-order)
LinkedList<T> visitaSIM()//THE ONE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO! should return the infos obtained with a symmetrical visit of the tree
```

I would be so thankful to everyone who can help me to write the last method.

Comment: Start with the [traversal of a binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) and see what you can come up with.

Comment: Already tried. I spent something like three hours on this visit alg, the only interesting thing I came up with was that I surely need two for cicles, one from 0 to arity/2, the other one from arity/2 to arity. Also I need to use a stack (LinkedList implementation)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a loop that for each node, visits the first `k/2` subtrees recursively.  After that returns, access the current node, then within a loop, recursively visit the remaining subtrees.